# React hook execute a function only once

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react and Mixpanel and I want to track when an user view a specific page.
I add the Mixpanel function on my page inside the useEffect, but my problem is that  I need this function to be render only once and only when I get data from my fetch (opportunity). I tried something like this :

```
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(clearContext());
        requestInitialData.forEach(fetcher => dispatch(fetcher(match.params)));
        scrollTop();
        let executed = false;
        if (opportunity) {
            executed = true;
            Mixpanel.track(`View a ${opportunity.activity.type} Event`, {
                ...mixpanelOpportunityInfos(opportunity),
            });
        }
    }, []);
```

Comment: have you tried [opportunity] instead of []?

Comment: Yes, it's a loop

Comment: i mean replacing the [] with [opportunity]